# Using a RegEx.Replace to replace matches with captures from two expressions

Tags: .net, regex, replace

I'm looking for a way to use RegEx to capture groups from two separate expressions, and use them for a search and replace in a single string with the captures shared between the two replaces.

For example:

```
string input_a = "abc-def-ghi";
string input_b = "123-4567-89";

string pattern_a = "(?<first>def)";  // captures 'def' from input_a and 
                                     // names the capture as 'first'
string pattern_b = "(?<second>456)"; // captures '456' from input_b and
                                     // names the capture as 'second'

string translation_a = "A=${first}${second}"; // replacement strings use the named
string translation_b = "B=${second}${first}"; // captures from both RegExs

// I want the results of the replace to give:

Console.Write("Result A: abc-A=def456-ghi"); // result of regex search and replace
                                             // matches on 'def' and replaces this
                                             // with 'A=' followed by 'def' from the 
                                             // first expression and '456' from the
                                             // second expression

Console.Write("Result B: 123-B=456def-789"); // same thing again but the other way
                                             // around
```

My inputs/patterns/translations are all not known at runtime as they are user configurable and stored in a database.

Can anyone suggest a neat elegant way to do this?

**UPDATE**

To give a little more context to my question, here is a real life example. I'm using this in a telecoms system that processes incoming calls. As calls come in, they have two pieces of information: the dialled number (known at the DDI) and the calling number (known as the CLI).

The system I'm creating needs to route numbers in a very dynamic configurable way using a list of 'rules' stored in a database, which are in fact a set of regular expressions. The rules need to be updated via a GUI, so nothing can be hard coded.

This part of the system does a kind of pre-routing translation on the incoming calls. Some examples include (this is all fictitious data):

```
DDI              CLI
800123400        01373000001
4150800123401    01373000002
123402077000000  01373000003
```

I need the calls to 'come out the other side' with their DDI and CLI translated. My database holds: DDISearchPattern, DDITranslation, CLISearchPattern, CLITranslation.

My first simple rule is:

```
DDISearchPattern = "^0?(?<ddi>\d{9})$"
DDITranslation   = "0${ddi}"
CLISearchPattern = "^0?(?<cli>\d{9})$"
CLITranslation   = "0${cli}"
```

Sometimes calls hit the system missing the leading zero. This rule will add it back on.

The next rule is to strip of a 415 prefix.

```
DDISearchPattern = "^4150?(?<ddi>\d{9})$"
DDITranslation   = "0${ddi}"
CLISearchPattern = "^0?(?<cli>\d{9})$"
CLITranslation   = "0${cli}"
```

But here is my problem. The in the last example (DDI = 123402077000000) I want to append the CLI to the end of the DDI, so I want to end up with 12340207700000001373000001.

I would like to be able to do this:

```
DDISearchPattern = "^12340?(?<ddi?\d{9})$"
DDITranslation   = "12340${ddi}${cli}"
CLISearchPattern = "^0?(?<cli>\d{9})$"
CLITranslation   = "0${cli}"
```

But unfortunately, the `${cli}` capture group is part of the CLI regex, not the DDI regex. How can I 'load up' one regex with the captured groups from the other regex, so that I can do a replace using the captures from both?

I have found a way to do this, but it's a very messy way using a regex to replace on `@'\$\{cli\}'`. I really want to find a simpler better way.

Comment: How is it "a single string" if you have two input strings, two translation strings and two output strings? I suppose you already know you can save the result and use `String.Format` to build the strings. The only thing you can combine is the regex to `(?<first>def)|(?<second>456)`, but that is rather pointless. I don't think I quite understand your question...

Comment: @Kobi: Maybe I should reword this slightly to make it clearer. By single string, I mean that captures from two expressions are combined and made available for search and replaces into another "single" string. My example just shows this happening twice, hence two results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit**
Ok, I see what your trying to do. Lets say the engine doesen't retain grouping values   between regexes.

What this would take is actually 2 passes of the each expression. First pass to capture   first/second, second pass to do the substitution with saved off firs/second values from   pass 1.

string pattern_a  = `"(?<first>def)";`
string pattern_b  = `"(?<second>456)";`

// run a match with pattern_a on input_a
string res_first  = `"${first}";`

// run a match with pattern_b on input_b
string res_second  = `"${second}";`

// run a replace pattern_a on input_a using res_first res_second
// run a replace pattern_b on input_b using res_first res_second
etc, ...

**end**

If I understand you correctly..
I don't know .net yet. But usually, a regex result is valid up until the next regex, after which the previous results are now invalid.

But if not, then you would need some more independent names.

```
string input_a = "abc-def-ghi";
string input_b = "123-4567-89";

string pattern_a = "^(?<apre>.*)(?<first>def)(?<apost>.*)$";
string pattern_b = "^(?<bpre>.*)(?<second>456)(?<bpost>.*)$";

string translation_a = "${apre}A=${first}${second}${apost}";
string translation_b = "${bpre}B=${second}${first}${bpost}";
```

If it is invalid, you need to save off the results after the first run. Something like this (warning, I am not familiar with catenation in .net):

```
string input_a = "abc-def-ghi";
string input_b = "123-4567-89";

string pattern_a = "^(?<pre>.*)(?<first>def)(?<post>.*)$";
string pattern_b = "^(?<pre>.*)(?<second>456)(?<post>.*)$";

// Do the regex for input_a
// Save off the capture vars here..

string A_pre   =  "${pre}"; 
string A_first =  "${first}"; 
string A_post  =  "${post}"; 

// Do the regex for input_b

string translation_a = A_pre + "A=" + A_first + "${second}";
string translation_b = "${pre}B=${second}" + A_first + "${post}";
```

Comment: This would be fine if my translation strings are fixed, but this is just an example of what I'm trying to do, in my real application all these strings are stored in a database, and can be changed at runtime, so nothing is known at compile time.

Comment: @BG100, ok, I see your dilema. The regex and replacement (and group names) are all in strings in a database. If they follow any consistency, you may be able to parse out the named capture groups. This will enable you to parse and substitute runtime variables to put in the translation replacement. A lot of work, but may be your only choice.

Comment: I know, I could probably do it like that but it wouldn't be very neat. Your examples have given me a few ideas though, I'll try a few more things. Thanks.